# Use spring security expressions in custom annotation

Tags: spring-security, aspectj

Hi I have a project with Spring boot + Spring Security.
I am building a custom annotation which I have defined like this:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface CustomAnnotation {
   String condition();
   String[] fields() default {};
}
```

This annotation will be applied on classes' methods. I want the "condition" parameter to be a 'spring security expression' which I will evaluate in an aspect that will evaluate the expression and if it is true , it will do some logic.

The Aspect is defined as follows:

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(customAnnotation)"  )
public void pointcutForCustomAnnotation(CustomAnnotation  customAnnotation) {
// Do nothing.
}

@Around("pointcutForCustomAnnotation(customAnnotation)")
public Object customAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, CustomAnnotation customAnnotation) throws Throwable   {
     // Here should go the logic to evaluate spring security expression
    String condition = customAnnotation.condition();
    String[] fieldsToHide = customAnnotation.fields();
}
```

When I mean Spring security expression , I mean the ones used in @Preauthorize, @PostAuthorize, @PreFilter @PostFilter spring annotations.
For example:

```
hasRole('ROLE_USER')
isAuthenticated()
```

How can I evaluate the spring security expression in the aspect ? I guess I could easily take the class i spring framework that does this job

Answer (score 0):

The following gist could be a point to start:

[Programmatically check Spring Security expressions](https://gist.github.com/matteocedroni/b0e5a935127316603dfb)

It worked for me with some adations for the same problem in Grails. (I had to change the expressionHandler lookup)